# Visual Studio 2010: "value does not fall within expected range" when trying to create a content type

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

Repro is like this: create an Empty SharePoint Solution, add new item, choose Content Type template, put a name, ok, it connects to a brand new test site, then I get the infamous "value does not fall within expected range".

Didn't get into debugging VS to get a stack etc, just wanted to ping here to know whether it's a known issue, I'm missing a VS patch, etc.

Ideas appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Ok, doesn't repro with another cleanly created VS SP empty solution...

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same type of behavior when creating content types using VS2010/SP2010. This is especially problematic if you're making changes to a previously deployed content type. The issue seems to stem from Visual Studio keeping a connection to SharePoint open and cacheing what is available (content types, etc.) for use in development. The best order I came up with for developing content types was this:

- Deploy Content Type
- Test
- Retract Solution
- Delete Solution
- Close and Reopen VS
- Reopen VS
- Repeat

Content Type definitions also seem to be more picky in SP2010 in regard to several items:

- { and } around your field IDs
- Requiring the name of the included field IDs
- Make sure to use Inherits, Overwrite, Version and FeatureID. This helped with making sure the content type was removed consistently, and redeployed consistently.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this happen when creating a content type where a folder of that name already existed on disk.

(because I had previously deleted a content type of that name from the project, but not from my hard disk)

Answer (score 0):

enlightened by http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/07/23/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-add-solution-value-does-not.aspx

i looked and found that i had a double GUID on my fields provision (i am using genesis)